# Hide if the JSON data is null

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I want to hide the whole tag if the JSON data is null.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/{{actorID.facebook_id}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

I'm using a get request to get the actor's external IDs and certain actors have facebook ID whereas certain actor's ID is null. How to hide the whole facebook icon if the JSON data is null.

Sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: ng-hide,ng-if??

Comment: Yes, Sample code will be appreciated! Please, share what you have tried.

Comment: use ng-if to hide or show the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-if to not render that tag :

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/{{actorID.facebook_id}}" target="_blank" ng-if="actorID.facebook_id"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

Use ng-show or ng-hide to hide tag:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/{{actorID.facebook_id}}" target="_blank" ng-show="actorID.facebook_id"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-if="actorID" href="https://www.facebook.com/{{actorID.facebook_id}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<a ng-if="actorId.facebook_id !== null" href="https://www.facebook.com/{{actorID.facebook_id}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

According to DOC:

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.